# How can I simplify $\nabla (X\cdot \nabla u)$?

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields, curl

What is $\nabla (X\cdot \nabla u)$ where $X:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector field and $u:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ a scalar field?

Comment: Product rule$\phantom{.}$?

Comment: Yes, but since $X$ and $\nabla u$ are then vector fields, I need to use the product rule that involves curl X and curl (\nabla u). How do I do this in two dimensions, not three?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure out what to do in two dimensions I will first go through all steps
in

***Three Dimensions***

For any two vector fields $X,Y$ in three dimensions
$$\tag{1}
X\times(\nabla\times Y)=\varepsilon_{ghi}\,X_h\,\varepsilon_{ijk}\,\partial_j\,Y_k
$$
where $\varepsilon_{abc}$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Vector_cross_product) and all indices appearing twice are summed over $1,2,3\,.$ These are here all indices, except $g\,.$

Using the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2)
$$\tag{2}
\varepsilon_{ghi}\,\varepsilon_{ijk}=\varepsilon_{igh}\,\varepsilon_{ijk}=\delta_{gj}\,\delta_{hk}-\delta_{gk}\,\delta_{hj}\,
$$
we get
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{ghi}\,\varepsilon_{ijk}\,\partial_j\,Y_k&=
\delta_{gj}\,\delta_{hk}\,\partial_j\,Y_k-
\delta_{gk}\,\delta_{hj}\,\partial_j\,Y_k\\
&=\partial_g\,Y_h-\partial_h\,Y_g\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Therefore the right hand side of (1) is
$$\tag{4}
X_h\,\partial_g\,Y_h-X_h\,\partial_h\,Y_g\,.
$$
Clearly, we can exchange $X$ and $Y$ to get
$$\tag{5}
Y\times(\nabla\times X)=Y_h\,\partial_g\,X_h-Y_h\,\partial_h\,X_g\,.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
X\times(\nabla\times Y)+Y\times(\nabla\times X)&=
X_h\,\partial_g\,Y_h+Y_h\,\partial_g\,X_h-X_h\,\partial_h\,Y_g-Y_h\,\partial_h\,X_g\\
&=\partial_g(X_hY_h)-X_h\,\partial_h\,Y_g-Y_h\,\partial_h\,X_g\\
&=\nabla(X\cdot Y)-(X\cdot\nabla)Y-(Y\cdot\nabla)Y\,.\tag{6}
\end{align}
In short
$$\tag{7}
\boxed{\phantom{\Bigg|}\quad X\times(\nabla\times Y)+Y\times(\nabla\times X)=\nabla(X\cdot Y)-(X\cdot\nabla)Y-(Y\cdot\nabla)X\,. \quad}
$$
With $Y=\nabla u$ where $u$ is a scalar function on $\mathbb R^3$
and using the well-known
$$\tag{8}
(\nabla\times (\nabla u))=\operatorname{rot grad}u=0
$$
the equation (7) gives
$$\tag{9}
\boxed{\phantom{\Bigg|}\quad (\nabla u)\times(\nabla\times X)=\nabla(X\cdot \nabla u)-(X\cdot\nabla)\nabla u-(\nabla u\cdot\nabla)X\, \quad}
$$
from which you can easily back out $\nabla(X\cdot \nabla u)\,.$

***Two Dimensions***

The two-dimensional analogue of (1) is (4) where $g$ and $h$ only run
through $\{1,2\}\,.$ With this in mind the middle part of (6) still holds:
\begin{align}
&X_h\,\partial_g\,Y_h+Y_h\,\partial_g\,X_h-X_h\,\partial_h\,Y_g-Y_h\,\partial_h\,X_g\\
&=\partial_g(X_hY_h)-X_h\,\partial_h\,Y_g-Y_h\,\partial_h\,X_g\,.\tag{10}
\end{align}
Again with $Y=\nabla u$ ($u$ now on $\mathbb R^2$) we get
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&\cancel{X_h\,\partial_g\,\partial_h\,u}+(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_g\,X_h)-\cancel{X_h\,\partial_h\,\partial_g\,u}-(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_h\,X_g)\\
&=\partial_g(X_h\,\partial_h\,u)-X_h\,\partial_h\,\partial_g\,u-(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_h\,X_g)\tag{11}
\end{align}
which can be written in mixed notation as
$$\boxed{\phantom{\Bigg|}\quad
(\nabla u)^\top(\partial_g\,X_h-\partial_h\,X_g)=\nabla(X\cdot\nabla u)
-(X\cdot \nabla)\,\nabla\,u-(\nabla u\cdot\nabla)\,X\,.\quad}\tag{12}
$$
You can again back out $\nabla(X\cdot\nabla u)\,.$ You should compare
(12) and (9).

Note that $(\partial_g\,X_h-\partial_h\,X_g)$ is an anti-symmetric $2\times 2$-matrix which we multiply from the left with the row vector $(\nabla u)^\top\,.$

***Remarks***

- There is nothing special about two dimensions. Formulas (10) to (12) obviously hold in every dimension. So do the following formulas:
- From a direct application of the product rule we obtain
  $$
  \nabla(X\cdot\nabla u)=\partial_g\,(X_h\,\partial_h\,u)=X_h\,\partial_g\,\partial_h\,u+(\partial_g\,X_h)(\partial_h\,u)\,.\tag{13}
  $$
  Clearly, $J_{gh}=\partial_g\,\partial_h\,u$ is the Jacobi matrix of $u$
  so that the first term on the right hand side could be written as
  $X^\top J\,.$
- In (11) we could have cancelled another two terms:
  \begin{align}\require{cancel}
  &(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_g\,X_h)-\bcancel{(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_h\,X_g)}\\
  &=\partial_g(X_h\,\partial_h\,u)-X_h\,\partial_h\,\partial_g\,u-\bcancel{(\partial_h\,u)\,(\partial_h\,X_g)}\tag{14}
  \end{align}
  which is nothing else than (13) as it must.

Answer (score 3):

We know from the gradient of a dot product of two vector fields that:

$$ \nabla (\vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}) =\vec{x} \times (\nabla \times \vec{v}) + \vec{v} \times (\nabla \times \vec{x}) + (\vec{x} \cdot \nabla) \vec{v}  + (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{x}$$

In your case, we have $\vec{v} = \nabla u$, replacing this in the expression above, we have:

$$ \nabla (\vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}) =\vec{x} \times (\nabla \times \nabla u) + \nabla u \times (\nabla \times \vec{x}) + (\nabla \cdot \vec{x}) \nabla u  + (\nabla u \cdot \nabla) \vec{x}$$

We then utilize the fact that the curl of a gradient is $0$. Hence, the first term vanishes. We are left with:

$$ \nabla (\vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}) =\nabla u \times (\nabla \times \vec{x}) + (\nabla \cdot \vec{x}) \nabla u  + (\nabla u \cdot \nabla) \vec{x}$$

I can't really see any more way to simplify this that would be beneficial, but maybe I'm forgetting something.

Comment: BTW, thanks for coming up with this. I should have remembered that phenomenal formula.